# Qual a tradução de "bom proveito" para Inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês, expressões-idiomáticas, significado-em-contexto

Eu faço a pergunta no título: Qual a tradução de "bom proveito" para Inglês? Mas não no sentido literal de:"Vais comer uma feijoada?! Bom proveito!"

Eu gostava de saber a tradução no sentido:"Ai vais fazer esse grande disparate?! Então, bom proveito!"

Ou seja, qual a tradução no sentido cínico e sarcástico da expressão?

Comment: Para falantes de inglês, pode ser útil relacioná-la a expressão "Bon appetit" do francês. Embora eles a usam apenas no contexto de aproveitar a refeição. A "bom proveito" pode ser usada em qualquer situação, inclusive é muito usada no Brasil de forma sarcástica, necessita de atenção ao contexto e tom da fala.

Comment: Acredito que em inglês se use mais "good luck/good luck with that" de forma sarcástica, mais do que uma tradução literal de "bom proveito"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode ser traduzido como "Enjoy it" ou "Put it to good use".

Comment: No meu entendimento, "[put it to good use](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/put-something-to-good-use)" não tem nenhum sentido insultuoso ou brejeiro. (O seu uso sarcástico pode dar um tom insultuoso; mas a frase em si é absolutamente neutra.)

Comment: Sim acho que tens razão @ANeves.

Comment: Está certinho. Pode ser: Enjoy it. Or: Enjoy yourself. [e não para comida] ou Put it good use. Mas as frases estão erradas. O verbo do não casa bem com bullshit e nonsense. So, you insist on this nonsense? Then, go ahead, enjoy it. AND So, you continue with this bullshit? Make sure to put it to good use.

Comment: Grato pelas correções e esclarecimentos Lambie.

Answer (score 1):

Outra expressão que vejo usada nesse sentido, expressando ironia e sarcasmo, seria <Be my guest!>